# Add all values with input name="TotalInline[]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

How to add values from all input with name `name="TotalInline[]"`?

The following does not seams to work:

```
    var total = 0;
    $.each('input[name="TotalInline[]"];,function() {
        total += this;
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work :

```
var total = 0;
$('input[name="TotalInline"]').each(function() {
    // assuming you have ints in your inputs, use parseFloat if those are floats
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10); 
});
```

Comment: I actually want to select with `name="SomeName[]"`, but after changing HTML syntax this will be good enough! Thanks.

Comment: The name actually has `[]` in it. You do not have that.

Comment: This wouldn't be a valid name. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: @dystroy - The spec you're linking to is outdated. Brackets are definitely welcome in `name` attributes. That's how you mark up arrays.

Comment: @dystroy HTML5 allows it, and PHP uses it to automatically build arrays. Most browsers actually allow "invalid" characters anyway.

Comment: @Blazemonger I didn't thought about PHP... That's true that you sometimes must do hacks against the current norm. Joseph, the current norm is HTML4 (but I agree that most browsers are using HTML5 today).

Answer (score 3):

```
var total = 0;
$.each($('input[name="TotalInline[]"]'), function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

Comment: I thought you'd have to \\ escape the brackets, but [apparently you don't](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jpbcf/).

Answer (score 2):

You have some serious syntax errors, try this:

```
var total = 0;
$('input[name="TotalInline[]"]').each(function () {
  total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
var total = 0;
$('input[name="TotalInline[]"]').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });
```

Comment: Though I like jQuery, `$(this).val()` is really not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;

$('input[name="TotalInline[]"]').each(function() {
    total += +this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
});
```

- Uses a quick regex to filter out only the numbers (and decimal point).
- Uses a `+` prefix to convert to a number.

Comment: Good tip with `+` for converting to number!